# running 20GB SQL script

Tags: sql, mysqli

I am running into an issue trying to execute a 20gb sql query using MySQL Workbench. obviously I would need to have 17+ gigs of RAM to load the .sql file but do not on this machine. Another idea I had would be to open it in a text editor and run bits at a time, but I cannot find a text editor that will open files larger than 4gb. Also I am trying to do this on a local machine so I don't lock the live server that is using this database
Any ideas for a work around?

Comment: Presumably lots of insert(lots)

Comment: Have you looked in the file to see if you can simply split it? (as you could in the above case)

Comment: Well it's an older DB for a tool but was done in process wire, when process wire was not needed. So basicly 23 tables with 16million records. Also for splitting it, only way I would know how is to open it in a text editor. Unless there is a different export using phpmyadmin.

Comment: Can you write your own program to read the text file a line at a time. Once you have a certain number of lines save to a separate file or run the sql

Comment: Doesn't MYSQL have an Command line tool to restore a database based on a script file? If this is the case i'm sure this tool read the file and execute it line by line, son memory won't be an issue

Comment: assuming you have access to a *nix like os `man split`  and just use that to split the file into manageable chunks

Comment: also as @ericpap said, you should just be able to pipe it mysql if it is a dump file created by phpmyadmin or the like.  It would execute line by line

Comment: I don't know how did you end up having a 20gigs script, but that is the point where the mistake was made...

Comment: Massive amount of data within the tables. I'm looking into piping it in now. Also I am on mac OSX

Answer (score 0):

I am prety sure HeidiSQL can do the trick size does not matter with HeidiSQL 
it executes wthout loading to the IDE
.and it is opensource